# What is causing this `ClassNotFoundException` while opening spark shell?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've downloaded a prebuilt version of Spark on my mac (OS Mavericks), but when I try to open an interactive shell, typing `bin/pyspark`, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.launcher.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

I have googled every part of the error and checkout out some other stack overflow threads, but I can't find anything that addresses this error.  Any idea what's going on/how to fix it?

One idea I have is that scala is a dependency that I need to download separately...but I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before, and it turned out to be a **permission issue** and I'm under user who has no access to the spark files (root downloaded spark).

Another possibility is, you downloaded the source code and **did not build the project** from source code :P

Hope it helps.